# How to get sales with rest API in magento 2?

Tags: api, magento2, rest-api

I have tried the following, but I get Consumer is not authorized to access %resources" error. Is there something I'm missing? Can you suggest another way to retrieve sales?

```
curl -X POST "http://magento2.app/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token"      -H "Content-Type:application/json"   -d '{"username":"admin", "password":"test1234"}
```

The token returned is: 5si930daobo3t529j8yq6xx3wp77x2vf
I plug it in the next request:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer  5si930daobo3t529j8yq6xx3wp77x2vf" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 366814d0-e058-7b89-c896-5670fb4fadb9" 'http://magento2.app/index.php/rest/V1/orders?criteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=status&criteria%5Bfilter_groups%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=processing'
```

error message is returned:

```
{"message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Sales::sales"}}
```

Magento 2 Rest API: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/restApi/restCollection/Magento/Sales/Service/V1/OrderList/orderList.html

Token-based authentication:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Comment: how can i inoke SOAP Service? I tried fallowed by http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html but unable to get result Could you please suggest me. see my thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76569/class-magento-testframework-testcase-webapi-adapter-soap-not-found-in-magento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try having only one space between 'Bearer' and the token. That worked for me (two spaces did not).

Comment: how can i inoke SOAP Service? I tried fallowed by http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/soap/soap-web-api-calls.html but unable to get result Could you please suggest me. see my thread http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76569/class-magento-testframework-testcase-webapi-adapter-soap-not-found-in-magento

Comment: i have same problem is there any solution?